# How to colorbox an entire section?

Tags: sectioning, colorbox

I want the last section of a chapter to have a colour background. I want to create a Summary section that needs to be differentiated.

I already tried using colorbox (xcolor package):

```
\colorbox{BurntOrange}{\section{Summary} .... }
```

But this always leads to errors. What is the proper way to add a background colour to a section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a couple of ideas: one based on `framed` (very light package but without many customization possibilities), and another based on `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

% for shaded/shaded*
\usepackage{framed} 
\colorlet{shadecolor}{red!10}

% for tcolorbox
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

% dummy text
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\kant[1]

\begin{shaded}
\vspace{-3.5ex}
\section{Summary}
\kant*[2]
\end{shaded}

\begin{shaded*}
\vspace{-3.5ex}
\section{Summary}
\kant*[2-3]
\end{shaded*}

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt,sharp corners,parbox=false,breakable,colback=blue!10]
\section{Summary}
\kant[4-5]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The boxes generated by `shaded` are always breakable. The text in `shaded` has normal width, and the box leaks into the margin; on the other hand, `shaded*` has a narrower text. The boxes of `tcolorbox` need the key `breakable` to be breakable (and `parbox=false` for paragraphs not to be ignored).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may helps you:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longfbox} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries\large}%\vspace{0pt}
{}
{0pt}
{\lfbox[border-style={solid, none, solid, none},background-color=blue!75,width =\linewidth-2\fboxsep]{\strut\thesection .~#1\strut}}%

\begin{document}

\section{Trial}

\end{document}
```

Note that I've used standard class file (`book`) as you are not provided `MWE`...

PS: Thanks to `Bernard` for his suggestion, but I missed the post link....sorry....

Comment: This makes a box only around the section title, doesn't it? The OP wants a box around the *whole* section.

Comment: @campa Do you mean the entire text in a box? Like `shaded` in `framed.sty`? Sorry, I didn't understand correctly...